# Paypal - PayFlow Pro, get transaction detail using 'Transaction Id'

Tags: api, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I have integrated '**Paypal - PayFlow Pro**' in my php website.
Using this api i receives transactions in my merchant account in '**manager.paypal.com**'. 
My concern is, I want to retrieve transaction details using **transaction id**.

So is there any API for payflow pro to retrieve transaction details using **transaction id**?

**Your answers are appreciated**

Answer (score 4):

Check https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/payflowgateway_guide.pdf, section **Submitting Inquiry Transactions**.

Here's an example: **TRXTYPE=I&TENDER=C&PARTNER=PayPal&VENDOR=SuperMerchant&USER=SuperMerchant&PWD=x1y2z3&ORIGID=VPNE12564395&VERBOSITY=HIGH**

You need to set ORIGID to **transaction id**.